# How to show ContentControl in designer when using Calibrun.Micro viewModel-first approach?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro (CM) in a WPF application with ViewModel-first approach. I'm composing the main view with a command bar and an active item. Main viewModel sets the property for the command bar viewModel, and navigates to active item correctly.

Everything looks fine at runtime, the issue is **only** related to design-time: the main view shows empty in designer and I cannot find how to set it correctly. I managed to having this working in other scenarios, e.g. when setting the datacontext at design time for a whole Window or UserControl, i.e. when that's the root UI element in XAML. But now I'm not able to to this for child ContentPresenter UI elements within a Window.

This is an excerpt of the *main view* I'm composing:

```xml
<Window x:Class="...MainView" ...>
  <DockPanel ...>
    <!-- this one binds to a property of type CommandBarViewModel -->
    <ContentControl x:Name="CommandBar" ... />
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" ... />
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I've checked a number of related reads, but none of them seems to fit/solve my issue. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536306/how-to-leverage-designer-when-using-a-viewmodel-first-approach-and-composition) is basically the same as mine, but has no answers. That has a reference to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107635/how-to-use-designinstance-with-caliburn-micro) which it seems to me is going for a View-first approach, judging by the `cal:View.Model` bindings.

I tried adding a design-time context like the following (`fake` namespace not shown for brevity):

```xml
<ContentControl x:Name="CommandBar" ... 
   d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=fake:DesignTimeCommandBarViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" 
   cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True"/>
```

but then I incur in one of two cases:

- if *DesignTimeCommandBarViewModel* inherits from the actual *CommandBarViewModel*, then I incur in somewhat the usual problem of design-time Vs dependency injection: the default constructor passes null for all injected dependencies, and base constructor or something else gives problem. I mean, it seems it would take some effort to find a workaround for this, and *just for* design-time support
- if *DesignTimeCommandBarViewModel* does not inherit from the actual viewModel, then it seems that (correctly) the CommandBarView is not instantiated, as now there's no relationship anymore between the viewModel and that view.

Have you got any idea about this? Maybe this should be solved with a design-time version of the hosting MainViewModel?

Other references I checked: [this answer, from Rob Eisenberg himself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997226/caliburn-micro-getting-it-to-bind-usercontrols-in-a-mainview-to-their-viewmodels), [this CM thread](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/267231), [this other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580325/does-caliburn-micro-play-nicely-with-user-controls)

**Edit**
Following my last (auto-)hint, I'm trying also creating and instantiating a  *DesignTimeMainViewModel*, **not** inheriting from *MainViewModel*, which exposes the same properties and sets a *DesignTimeCommandBarViewModel* in its default constructor. In this case, in place of the command bar the designer shows the classic CM complaint: cannot find view for the DesignTimeCommandBarViewModel.
What's next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's the solution I found: I'd be glad to hear about better ways or other suggestions.

Host *MainView* XAML specifies a design-time data-context pointing to a design-time version of the Main view-model which, by the way, does **not** inherit from the runtime version *MainViewModel*. *ContentControl* items are left untouched.

```xml
<Window x:Class="...MainView" ...
  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=fake:DesignTimeMainPanelViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
  cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">

  <DockPanel ...>
    <ContentControl x:Name="CommandBar" ... />
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" ... />
  </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

*DesignTimeMainPanelViewModel* has the same public properties as *MainPanelViewModel*, has a default c'tor without dependencies and its c'tor sets the *CommandBar* property to a new instance of *DesignTimeCommandBarViewModel*:

```cs
public class DesignTimeMainPanelViewModel
{
    public DesignTimeMainPanelViewModel()
    {
        CommandBar = new DesignTimeCommandBarViewModel();
        ActiveItem = ...some instance here as well...;
    }

    public DesignTimeCommandBarViewModel CommandBar { get; private set; }
    public IScreen ActiveItem { get; private set; }
}
```

*DesignTimeCommandBarViewModel* class is decorated with a custom Attribute having only one required parameter, the *System.Type* of the view associated with that view-model.

During bootstrap the code adds a new *ViewLocator* strategy to get the view Type from the view-model Type, by setting a new *ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType*.

The new locator function will try to find a view Type if the standard locator function cannot find one. Granted, it will look for the custom attribute on view-model Type, and if found that would be the returned view Type. Here's the gist of that:

```cs
Type viewType = _previousLocate(viewModelType, displayLocation, context);

if (viewType == null)
{
    FakeViewAttribute fakeViewAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(viewModelType, typeof(FakeViewAttribute)) as FakeViewAttribute;

    if (fakeViewAttr != null) viewType = fakeViewAttr.ViewType;
}

return viewType;
```

Comment: Some time later, this methods does not work reliably. Recently I see more and more the *Cannot find view for* message in VS designer. I also switched the view locator customization: instead of specifing the View type in attributes I specify the ViewModel type, from which I infer the View type. But still this is not working

Comment: As of today, there's still progress on discussion [here](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/388#issuecomment-312887906)